# GoogleCloudMessaging Android client: IntentService truly necessary?

Tags: android, architecture, google-cloud-messaging

Google's [Implementing GCM Client](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) documentation demonstrates an architectural pattern wherein a [WakefulBroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) kicks off an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), which in turn actually processes the incoming cloud message, and notifies the receiver when finished. In the example, and in the application I am writing, the only real work to be done is the creation and posting of a system [Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Creating and posting a Notification are short-lived tasks, and require no asynchronous calls/responses. Now I can understand the need for a Service to handle some long-running task upon receipt of a Cloud Message (and indeed, Google's example code simulates such a task). But, assuming that the only thing to be done upon receipt of a Cloud Message is the posting of a Notification, is the IntentService intermediary truly necessary? Is there some pitfall I'm overlooking if I just use a plain-Jane [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) to catch the Cloud Message, parse some JSON, and send a Notification?

Comment: In "Receive a message" section there are a note which should respond to your question

Comment: And I thought I read the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, assuming that the only thing to be done upon receipt of a Cloud Message is the posting of a Notification, is the IntentService intermediary truly necessary?

So long as you do not need to do any disk I/O or network I/O, you should be fine with just an ordinary `BroadcastReceiver`. Your JSON will be short, so that parsing work should be quick, and posting a `Notification` is also quick.